Show that $A = \mathbb N$.
I have a question regarding the following exercise: "Let $A \subseteq \mathbb N$ with the following properties:
$1 \in A$ and $\forall n\in A$ it ist true that $2n \in A$ and $2n+1 \in A$." Now, my proof is the following: Let $m = 2n$. Then it is true that $A \subseteq \mathbb N$ and $1 \in A$ and for all $m \in A \implies m+1\in A$. Therefore $A = \mathbb N$. (in the last step I applied a result we derived in a lecture, which was titled "Principle of induction" (translated from the German "Prinzip der vollständigen Induktion). Is this proof sufficient, or am I missing something? It seems very short.

You can't just assume that $m=2n$ is an even number. And even if it is, how do you know your $n$ really belongs to $A$? It's not that simple. I suggest to prove by induction that $n\in A$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

If you want to use induction, you also need the base step, which is probably a good start by showing that $2 \in A$.

There's something weird in your reasoning

Let $m = 2n$

Why do you assume that? You are supposed to take any $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and show that $m\in A$. Moreover there is no clear way to show that "if $m\in A$ then $m+1\in A$" implication. That would be true if $n\in A$, which isn't clear at all.

Anyway, you are correct that an induction has to be used here. We will use a different variant of induction:

Assume that $A\subseteq \mathbb N$ satisfies the following two properties:

$1\in A$
Assume that for any $m\in \mathbb N$ we have $n\in A$ for all $n<m$. Then $m\in A$.

Then $A=\mathbb N$

This variant is equivalent to the standard "$m\in A\Rightarrow m+1\in A$" variant.

So let $A\subseteq\mathbb N$ be such that $1\in A$ and whenever $n\in A$ then $2n\in A$ and $2n+1\in A$. We will use induction. The first condition is clearly satisfied.
Now assume that $m\in\mathbb{N}$ is given such that $n\in A$ for all $n<m$. Since every number is either even or odd, then either $m=2s$ for some $s$ or $m=2t+1$ for some $t$. Both $s,t$ are necessarily lower than $m$. The $m=1$ case can be excluded (this case implies $t=0$ which we don't deal with in this context). Therefore by our induction hypothesis $s,t\in A$, and thus $m\in A$ by our assumption on $A$. Therefore induction property 2 is satisfied, and thus $A=\mathbb N$.

Thank you. I thought something was fishy, but couldn't quite figure it out for some reason.

To avoid the correctors wrath, would it be correct to let $m \in \mathbb N \setminus {1}$, so I exclude $m=1$ right off the bat?

We can exclude $m=1$ because property 1 takes care of it. So yes, taking $m\in\mathbb{N}\backslash{1}$ at the beginning is a good idea.
